# Ios tabed application @property

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I am a beginner in Ios developement and I'm developping a tabed application but I would like a property accessible from each view so i write this in appDelegate:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *test;`
But now I don't know how to access this string from my firstViewController.m and secondViewController.m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create Object of Appdelegate class like:-

```
AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

and used this defined string in any class using `del.test`. Do not forget to import your Appdelegate class in to particular class that you want to use it's string. And also `@synthesize` your string in .m `appdelegate` class as well.

**UPDATE:-**

If you wish to use Appdelegate Object in particular class then Import App-delegate in to .h file like:-

[image]

and .m class in `ViewDidLoad`

[image]

Comment: Type casting the delegate instance to `AppDelegate` class will avoid warnings. `AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];`

Comment: sir if you are not import Appdelegate class in to particular class then you got warning. if you can't beleve then i add screenshot without warning. i used this line of code that i attach in to my answer. and in other case are you define object of appdelegate in .h file and used this object wia particular class then you are right. with above